# How to use just one struct for doubly linked list

Tags: c, struct, doubly-linked-list

Lately, I've been giving myself a try as a beginner, at doubly-linked lists, here is my piece of code that allocates memory for a doubly-linked list:

```c
typedef struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *prev;
                } NodeT;
typedef NodeT *NodePointer;

typedef struct secondtag
{
       NodeT *head;
       NodeT *tail;
}doublyll;

/* function prototypes */
doublyll *Create(void);



/* MAIN */
int main(void)
{

doublyll *L=Create();

}



// create_list:  returns a pointer to a new empty list or NULL
doublyll *Create(void)
{ 
    NodeT *NodePointer;
    doublyll *new_list=malloc(sizeof(*new_list));

if(new_list!=NULL)
{
    new_list->head = NULL;
    new_list->tail = NULL;
}
NodePointer->next=0;
NodePointer->prev=0;
return new_list;
}
```

My question is the following: is there a way I can write the two structs I've made, `Node` and `secondtag`, into a single 1 struct?

Comment: It is common practice to either create just a ```Node``` struct and let the user handle ```head``` and ```tail```, or create 2 like you did, one for ```Node``` and a wrapper for a doubly-linked list like you did with ```doublyll```. So don't bother trying to merge those 2 together.

Comment: You *could* use only `Node`s and get rid of `secondtag` altogether.  But that would put more work on the client because they would have to manually keep track of `head` and `tail` themselves.  Maybe I should ask: *why* do you want only one struct?

Comment: @0x5453 It is not that i specifically want to have one struct, however, as i said i am a beginner when it comes to DLL's and i am experimenting. Thank you for your awnser.

Comment: Just FYI, this is broken from inception anyway: `NodePointer->next=0;` = *undefined behavior*. `NodePointer` is uninitialized. From what I see it is completely pointless to even have at all in that function.

Comment: I suggest reading how linked lists are done in Linux kernel. See https://medium.com/@414apache/kernel-data-structures-linkedlist-b13e4f8de4bf